# Nunit 3.00 is not running tests

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit, appium, nunit-3.0

Nunit 3 isn't running tests, while I'm running tests with 2.64 everything works like a charm. 
on version 3, I'm not getting any errors or anything. it just won't run.

I'm running my tests with Selenium-C# and Appium.

Comment: Are You are using Visual Studio 2015?

Comment: no. should I? I'm using VS2013

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never use `Selenium-C# and Appium` but common problem is if You start using `NUnit 3` is `NUnit Test Adapter`.

NUnit Test Adapter for previous version of NUnit 2 won't work, test don't appear in test explorer etc.

To solve this You must install a `NUnit 3 Test Adapter`.

Here is a link for package:

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0da0f6bd-9bb6-4ae3-87a8-537788622f2d

Comment: Assuming he is using any adapter at all, that is. The OP doesn't actually say how he is trying to run the tests. :-)